# Not able to connect by using network on docker to mongodb running in docker container other container with node js

Tags: node.js, mongodb, docker, dockerfile

I have created a network within a docker with name **favorites-net** and two containers with the name following :-

1). mongodb (its running properly image from docker hub mongodb).

2). favorites (with having simple nodejs project which try to connect with mongodb database)

**Connection Code Which i have used**

```
mongoose.connect(
  // 'mongodb://localhost:27017/swfavorites',  ###Working Properly by using this###
  'mongodb://mongodb:27017/swfavorites',       ### Not Working by using this###
  { useNewUrlParser: true },
  (err) => {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
    } else {
      app.listen(3000);
    }
  }
);
```

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM node

WORKDIR /app

COPY package.json .

RUN npm install

COPY . .

CMD ["node", "app.js"]
```

**Commond Use To Build Image**

```
docker build -t favorites-node .
```

**Command Use To Run Node Js Container**

```
docker run --name favorites --network favorites-net -d -p 
3000:3000 favorites-node
```

**MongoDB Container up in running status**

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS               NAMES  
56aeba0a7f2f        mongo               "docker-entrypoint.s…"   55 minutes ago      Up 14 seconds       27017/tcp           mongodb
```

**Error Got when checking `docker logs favorites`**

```
MongoNetworkError: failed to connect to server [mongodb:27017] on first connect [Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND mongodb
    at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (node:dns:67:26) {
  name: 'MongoNetworkError'
}]
    at Pool.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/topologies/server.js:438:11)
    at Pool.emit (node:events:376:20)
    at /app/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/connection/pool.js:562:14
    at /app/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/connection/pool.js:995:11
    at /app/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/connection/connect.js:32:7
    at callback (/app/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/connection/connect.js:280:5)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/connection/connect.js:310:7)
    at Object.onceWrapper (node:events:483:26)
    at Socket.emit (node:events:376:20)
    at emitErrorNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:188:8)
    at emitErrorCloseNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:153:3)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:80:21)
```

Comment: Please don't use screenshots to show code

Comment: @Anatoly sorry for that i have remove screenshots  and reformatted it. Can you please suggest to me how to fix the issue.

Comment: Errors from terminal also should be as a text if possible. And please show both docker files describing these two containers. Don't you use docker-compose?

Comment: I have also added the error from the terminal getting and all other files above.

Comment: ok thanks, I got the solution problem with my MongoDB not with the same network in which my nodejs container is running in docker now its working fine

Answer (score 1):

The mongodb port is not published,

please run mogodb container with port published
`docker run -d --name mongodb -p 27017:27017 --network favorites-net mongo`

Comment: we are using the same network bridge for both node js and docker container any they internally connected show we do not need to defend the external port 
-p <external_port>:<port_within_conatiner> it will work fine.

Comment: Yes you are right @MayankRai, in user_defined_bridge_network all ports are open to all services connected to the network

Answer (score 0):

*problem with my MongoDB not with the same network in which my nodejs container is running in docker now it's working fine*

**Command used to run MongoDB with the same network**

```
docker run -d --name mongodb --network favorites-net mongo
```